# How to sum multiple items in an object in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell

I have:

```
$report.gettype().name
Object[]

echo $report

Item                       Average
--                         -------
orange                     0.294117647058824
orange                    -0.901960784313726
orange                    -0.901960784313726
grape                      9.91335740072202
grape                      0
pear                       3.48736462093863
pear                      -0.0324909747292419
pear                      -0.0324909747292419
apple                     12.1261261261261
apple                     -0.0045045045045045
```

I want to create a variable, $total, (such as a hash table) which contains the sum of the 'Average' column for each item, for example,

```
echo $total

orange  -1.5097
grape    9.913
pear     3.423
apple   12.116
```

Right now I'm thinking of looping through the $report, but it's hell ugly, and I am looking for something more elegant than the following starting point (incomplete):

```
$tmpPrev = ""
foreach($r in $report){
    $tmp = $r.item
    $subtotal = 0
    if($tmp <> $tmpPrev){
        $subtotal += $r.average
    }
```

How could I do this?

Answer (score 70):

Cmdlets [Group-Object](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849907.aspx) and [Measure-Object](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849965.aspx) help to solve the task in a PowerShell-ish way:

Code:

```
# Demo input
$report = @(
    New-Object psobject -Property @{ Item = 'orange'; Average = 1 }
    New-Object psobject -Property @{ Item = 'orange'; Average = 2 }
    New-Object psobject -Property @{ Item = 'grape'; Average = 3 }
    New-Object psobject -Property @{ Item = 'grape'; Average = 4 }
)

# Process: group by 'Item' then sum 'Average' for each group
# and create output objects on the fly
$report | Group-Object Item | %{
    New-Object psobject -Property @{
        Item = $_.Name
        Sum = ($_.Group | Measure-Object Average -Sum).Sum
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Sum Item
--- ----
  3 orange
  7 grape
```

Answer (score 11):

I've got a more command-line solution.

Given $report

```
$groupreport = $report | Group-Object -Property item -AsHashTable
```

is

```
Name     Value
----     -----
grape    {@{Item=grape; Average=9.91335740072202}, @{Item=grape; Average=0}}
orange   {@{Item=orange; Average=0.294117647058824}, @{Item=orange; Average=-0.901960784313726...
apple    {@{Item=apple; Average=12.1261261261261}, @{Item=apple; Average=-0.0045045045045045}}
pear     {@{Item=pear; Average=3.48736462093863}, @{Item=pear; Average=-0.0324909747292419}, @...
```

then

```
$tab=@{}
$groupreport.keys | % {$tab += @{$_ = ($groupreport[$_] | measure-object -Property average -sum)}}
```

gives

```
PS> $tab["grape"]

Count    : 2
Average  :
Sum      : 9,91335740072202
Maximum  :
Minimum  :
Property : Average

PS> $tab["grape"].sum
9,91335740072202
```

It seems short and usable.

**Summary**

```
$groupreport = $report | Group-Object -Property item -AsHashTable
$tab = @{}
$groupreport.keys | % {$tab += @{$_ = ($groupreport[$_] | measure-object -Property average -sum)}}
$tab.keys | % {write-host $_ `t $tab[$_].sum}
```

Answer (score 5):

I don't know if you can get rid of looping. What about:

```
$report | % {$averages = @{}} {
    if ($averages[$_.item]) {
        $averages[$_.item] += $_.average
    }
    else {
        $averages[$_.item] = $_.average
    }
} {$averages}
```

Comment: thanks empo... i'm getting: The splatting operator '@' cannot be used to reference variables in an expressi
on. '@averages' can be used only as an argument to a command. To reference vari
ables in an expression use '$averages'.  .... is this a problem at my end, or a problem with the code?

Comment: @ted: I'm sorry. That was a miscode, now corrected. I'm still little sleepy ;-)

Comment: The `if($averages[$_.item])` check is not necessary, since the value of a missing hashtable item will be treated as zero in an arithmetic expression like `+=`: `$report | % { $averages = @{} } { $averages[$_.Item] += $_.Average } { $averages }`