# Powershell Group By Multiple Properties

Tags: powershell

I am trying to determine if there's an easier way to write a Powershell function that groups an array by multiple properties and sums specified properties in the group, similar to the following:

```
#Ungrouped data
ID ID2 Value
-- --- -----
A  A1    100
A  A2    200
A  A2    300
B  B1    400
B  B1    500
B  B1    600
B  B3    700
C  C1    800
C  C2    900
C  C1   1000

#Grouped data
ID ID2 Sum Value
-- --- ---------
A  A1        100
A  A2        500
B  B1       1500
B  B3        700
C  C1       1800
C  C2        900
```

Here's what I have so far:

```
$grouped = $ungrouped | group ID, ID2
$grouped | foreach {
    [pscustomobject] @{
        ID = $_.group | select -unique -expand ID
        ID2 = $_.group | select -unique -expand ID2
        'Sum Value' = ($_.group | measure value -sum).sum
    }
}
```

This works for me, but I just get the feeling I'm overdoing it and there may be a more concise way to write this, especially if I was grouping by more properties and wanted to sum up or aggregate more grouped values.

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: What's your problem? As that's a fairly common way to do that (check out [JPBlanc's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5999930/how-to-sum-multiple-items-in-an-object-in-powershell) if you want to make a hash table) - otherwise you should move this to [code review.SE](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 11):

I have the same, perhaps a bit simpler, I remove two `|`

```
$grouped = $ungrouped | group ID, ID2
$grouped | foreach {
    $b= $_.name -split ', '
    [pscustomobject] @{
         ID = $b[0];ID2 = $b[1]
        'Sum Value' = ($_.group | measure value -sum).sum
    }
}
```

One liner :

```
Import-Csv 'YourFile.csv' | Group-Object -Property ID,ID2 | % {$b=$_.name -split ', ';$c=($_.group | Measure-Object -Property value -Sum).Sum;[PScustomobject]@{ID=$b[0];ID2=$b[1];Sum=$c}}
```

Comment: `$b= $_.name -split ', '` -> `$id, $id2 = $_.name -split ', '` (then no need for `$b[n]`)